# How to get the number of words from a line from a text file

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, iteration, text-files

I am trying to get the number of words from a line in a text file. I used .getline() in order to extract a line from the entire text file. The code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    char const* filename = "duck.txt";
    std::ifstream ifs{ filename };
    constexpr size_t MAX_LINE_LEN{ 2048 };
    char line[MAX_LINE_LEN];

    int lineCount = 0;
    int totalWordCount = 0;
    int totalByteCount = 0;

    while (ifs.getline(line, MAX_LINE_LEN-1))
    {
        int lineWord = 0;

        char* q = &line[0];

        if (ifs.eof())
        {
            lineCount--;
            totalByteCount--;
        }

        while (*q != '\0')
        {
            q++;
            totalByteCount++;
        }
        totalByteCount++;

        if (*q == '\0')
        {
            lineCount++;
        }

        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        while (line[i] != '\0' && line[j] != '\0')
        {
            while (line[i] == ' ')
            {
                i++;
            }

            j = i;

            while (line[j] != ' ')
            {
                j++;
            }

            lineWord++;

            j = i;
        }

        totalWordCount += lineWord;
    }

    std::cout << "Total Lines: " << lineCount << '\n' << "Total Words: " << totalWordCount << '\n' << "Total Bytes: " << totalByteCount;
}
```

But the only important part is:

```
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        while (line[i] != '\0' && line[j] != '\0')
        {
            while (line[i] == ' ')
            {
                i++;
            }

            j = i;

            while (line[j] != ' ')
            {
                j++;
            }

            lineWord++;

            j = i;
        }

        totalWordCount += lineWord;
```

I'm trying to read the line character by character until I reach a non-whitespace character after which I'll assign that subscript to i. Then, I'll set j to the subscript of the first whitespace encountered after the character of line[i]. If j finds a whitespace, then there is a word. If j reaches '\0', then the line has ended and I end the while loop. When I try to compile and run this, the compiler just displays nothing. What am I doing wrong? Also, I can't add anymore header files

Comment: The inner-most whiles will race past the end of the string. All you need to do is count the whitespace caracters in the string. (Bonus points for handling consecutive whitesepace.)

Answer (score 0):

In your original code:

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;

while (line[i] != '\0' && line[j] != '\0')
{
    while (line[i] == ' ')  // you do not check for end of string character?
    {
        i++;
    }

    j = i;   // here i = j = beginning of word.

    // since you rewind to beginning of the word below,
    // your program keeps repeating this loop endlessly

    while (line[j] != ' ')  // this loop could easily run for quite a while.
                            // until it seg-faults
    {
        j++;
    }

    lineWord++;

    j = i;  // BUG Here!  you're 'rewinding' j to to beginning of the word.
            // you loop back and keep counting the same word over and over.
}

totalWordCount += lineWord;
```

What is the purpose of i and j ?  Wouldn't the code be simpler and easier to read and maintain using a single pointer?  Or a single index?  This kind of algorithm is where a pointer would excel, though, as the only arithmetic pointer operation needed is increment.

As in:

```
const char* p = &line[0];
int word_count = 0;

line[MAX_LINE_LEN - 1] = 0;  // making sure the code below stays within boundaries.

for(;;)
{
    // skip to next word
    while (*p && *p == ' ') ++p;  // stay within the string by testing for zero.

    if (!*p)
        break;  // done!
   
    // since p now points to the beginning of a word, we've got one
    ++word_count;

    // skip to end of word
    while (*p && *p != ' ') ++p;
}
```

This is all fine, for most cases but there could be some exceptional typos in the text, like `"hello, world !"`, where the last punctuation would be counted as a word.  There is also the problem of horizontal tabs, which could also be counted erroneously as words.

To cover these cases, you should test for valid characters for words, instead of for space, which is a rather vague concept.

Without using library calls, You'd need to define what constitutes spaces and punctuation, either with a constant, or with a function.

Substituting the test for space with a more targeted test, using isalnum() to check for alpha or numeric characters:

```
for(;;)
{
    // skip to next word
    while (*p && !std::isalnum(*p & 0xFF)) ++p;  

    if (!*p)
        break;  // done!
   
    ++word_count;

    // skip to end of word
    while (*p && std::isalnum(*p & 0xFF)) ++p;
}
```

Beware of function of the isalnum(), isalpha().. family, they define their input as an `int`, the mask ensures that characters in the 128-255 range are not sign-extended aand are passed correctly as positive values.